# Archetypes packages - how to create your own?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, homebrew, class-feature

The archetype packages are a sort of "alternative" for the typical archetypes in Pathfinder. In my game table, we continuously creating new archetypes (not necessarily "balancing") and the option of the archetype packages seems reasonable solution for creation of some unique hybrid classes and cool ideas.

In this way, searching for the books with that packages, I found myself with the desire to create my own. The thing is: assuming those packages have "balanced" all the abilities with the each other that are lost, for example:

- What the impact giving a rogue the "rage" feature?
- A rogue with the paladin spell list would be more nerfed than powered?

Answer (score 5):

There's no absolute answer for every specific power as this isn't GURPS, but [in the Advanced Class Guide they published some guidance](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/advancedClassGuide/designingClasses.html) for creating classes, archetypes, etc.